# TSX CSS conditional rendering always giving true statment

Tags: css, reactjs, tsx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aq3mQ.png)

transform: aboutMe => (aboutMe ? "translateY(-500%)" : "translateY(0%)")

So I used to run my React project and use MaterialUi's MakeStyles to include the CSS in the same tsx file and benefit from the JavaScript code to do conditional renderings. Now I am changing my project to Gatsby, but for some reason the above code isn't working and it's considering the statment to be true all the time although I'm console logging it and it's working the way it's supposed to. Any idea why here the statment is always considered true?

```
import React from "react"
import { StaticImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles"
interface Props {
  aboutMe: boolean
  aboutMeOpen: () => void
}
export default function Background(props: Props) {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const { aboutMe, aboutMeOpen } = props
  return (
    <div className={classes.body}>
      <div className={classes.effect}>
        <StaticImage
          src="../../images/backgroundEffect.png"
          alt="effect"
          quality={50}
          draggable={false}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  effect: {
    zIndex: 10,
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
    // userSelect: "none",
    // height: "100%",
    transition: "0.5s",
    transform:  aboutMe => ( aboutMe ? "translateY(100%)" : "translateY(0%)"),
  },
})
```

Comment: Can you share the full component?

Comment: What value is passed into `aboutMe`?

Comment: What you've shared uses the `aboutMe` value. But, if you're wondering why it's `true`, you need to look at where the value's set, not where it's used. Check your code and edit the question to include the relevant portions, and people might be able to help.

Comment: I've included the code in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 2 className:

```
<div className={aboutMe ? classes.effect1 : classes.effect1 } >
```

Or add inline style:

```
<div className={classes.effect} style={{trasform:  aboutMe ? "translateY(100%)" : "translateY(0%)"}} >
```

Or you can pass params to `useStyles` like this:

```
const classes = useStyles({ aboutMe: props.aboutMe });

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  effect: ({ aboutMe }) => ({
    // ...
    backgroundColor: aboutMe ? "translateY(100%)" : "translateY(0%)",
  }),
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I know these solutions, but my question is is there any way I can include my JS code in the CSS (the way I did in the component) and benefit from the conditional rendering?

Comment: I updated my answer. Hope it can help